# How can I slide a Form under the Windows taskbar and set transparency off?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that pops out from under the taskbar. So far so good. But in the case of a transparent taskbar, the Form can't be seen first under the taskbar and only then on top of eveything else and I don't like this effect.

[image]

Can I somehow disable the transparency of the Windows Taskbar for a few milliseconds? Or maybe some other ideas?

Comment: can you rephrase what you don't like?

Comment: Why not let the window sit 'on top' of the taskbar? Instead of behind it? You probably could disable the transparency (as it is an configurable option in Windows) but it probably involves a lot of nasty Win32 API calls and would be hard to get stable.

Comment: `Can I somehow disable the transparency of the Windows Taskbar for a few milliseconds?` How would that improve the experience? A taskbar going from transparent to opaque and back would cause a lot of flicker and thus annoy the user. Also, you're [trying to solve a local problem with a global solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @GeraldVersluis: Have the popup sit atop the taskbar.  You can do this (eg, get the lower edge of your screen area) by interrogating the Screen object.  [`Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea)